# AngularJS $http vs $http.post

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS and trying my hands on it.

I want to send data to server and map it to DTO in one of the REST Service.
So I did it in this way,

```
         saveUserUrl = "http://localhost:8080/App/rest/UserManager/saveUser";

         var results = [];
         for (var i = $scope.users.length; i--;) {
             var user = $scope.users[i];
             results.push(user);
         }
         $http.post(saveUserUrl, {
                data: results,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Authorization':$routeParams.auth },
                transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
                    return data;
                }
            }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(status == 203) {
                    alert("Session Timed out, Please Login Again");
                    $window.location=getContextFromURL();
                }else{
                    alert("user saved success");
                }
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("user saved failure");
            });
```

Payload going as

```
{"data":
    [{"id":2,"name":"Agent3","extn":3,"group":1,"groupName":"Agent","isNew":false},
     {"id":1,"name":"Agent2","extn":"2","group":1,"groupName":"Agent","isNew":false}
    ],
 "headers":
    {"Authorization":"5825ccb2-d28b-47e6-87a8-0b31f8ec9a78"}
}
```

REST Service

```
@POST
@Path("/saveUser")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON} )
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON} )
public Response saveUser(@HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authorization,@Context HttpServletRequest req, DBUserEntity dbUser  ) {
    System.out.println("User iiss :" + dbUser);
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(200);
    //System.out.println("zipStatus :"+zipStatus);
    //TODO
    return responseBuilder.entity(null).build();
}
```

Everything is working fine.

Now I tried with this way as generalised function for all the server calls and it stopped working

```
$http({ 
            url: urlBase+requestMapping, 
            method: method, 
            data: formData, 
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': contentType, 
                'Authorization':$routeParams.auth
            }, 
            transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
                return data; // do nothing! FormData is very good!
            }
        });
```

And it stopped working.
payload going as:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

I tried JSON.stringify and then it passed as

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Agent23",
        "extn": 23,
        "group": 1,
        "groupName": "Agent",
        "isNew": false,
        "$$hashKey": "object:11"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Agent22",
        "extn": "22",
        "group": 1,
        "groupName": "Agent",
        "isNew": false,
        "$$hashKey": "object:10"
    }
]
```

I dont know the correct working of $http vs $http.post, is there any specific things that need to take care while each way of sending data.

Comment: did you ever find the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post` is just a shortcut method for `$http` with `method:'POST'`.
In your example, running

```
$http({ 
        url: saveUserUrl, 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: results,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Authorization':$routeParams.auth },
        transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
            return data;
        }
    });
```

should yield exactly the same result as your original `$http.post` request

Comment: It is not sending the same Payload or I am doing something wrong, I have post the payload as well, it is not sending.

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? Do you get any response from the server?

Comment: same URL is for both, in 1st case it is working and in 2nd case it is not as payload is different and it is not able to map to proper REST service method.

Comment: @yarons I am having the same issue. The question is why is the JSON being sent back to the service nested one level too deep when using $http.post as opposed to $http with method: POST?